# ipcs doesn't show my shared memory and semaphores

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory, ipcs

I open shared memory and semaphores with the appropriate flags:

```
sem = sem_open("/some_name", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO, 1);
shm = shm_open("/other_name", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
```

The calls don't fail (I check them) and indeed one process who `fork`/`exec`s other processes creates them and the other processes do share the memory and semaphores and there is proper synchronization.

When I use the `ipcs` command however, I don't see the shared memory nor the semaphore. Why is that? If they don't appear with `ipcs`, where can I check them?

---

In my `ipcs` output I don't have any entries in the Semaphore Array list and the ones in shared memory are related to skype, firefox and plugin-container (of firefox). I checked them with

```
grep shmid /proc/*/maps     # observe pid
readlink /proc/pid/exe
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution I just found was that shared memory and shared semaphores are listed under:

```
/dev/shm
```

The files there are useful for knowing what shared objects there are and maybe to `unlink` them, but they don't provide any useful information beyond that (as `ipcs` does).

Answer (score 5):

Ipcs reports only System V shared memory. You must be using Posix shared memory. Apparently these are two completely different mechanisms. Posix shm is shown under /dev/shm.

I've had the same issue, and the accepted answer is not satisfying enough as it is not explaining why this is happening. I found the answer in another similar question:
[i cannot see the shared memory created by the boost::interprocess via shell command ipcs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021045/i-cannot-see-the-shared-memory-created-by-the-boostinterprocess-via-shell-comm)

"As far as I'm aware, ipcs reports only System V shared memory. POSIX shared memory is a separate area, and has to be queried separately. On linux systems, check /dev/shm."

Answer (score -1):

In my case the solution was to use **sudo**:

```
sudo ipcs -m
```